# How to enable quick look preview in OmniOutliner 3.10.6 on osx11.2?

Tags: quicklook, omnioutliner

After installing El Capitan, the contents of OmniOutliner Pro 3.10.6 files are no longer visible (I know there is a newer version but I'm not interested spending the money).

Is there a way to re-enable quick look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download a recent version of OmniOutliner, in my case I used 'OmniOutliner-4.4.1.dmg'

Mount the dmg and right click on the app icon and choose 'Show Package Contents'

Navigate to:

'OmniOutliner.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/OmniOutlinerMetadataImporter.mdimporter'

and copy it to:

'/Library/Spotlight/OmniOutlinerMetadataImporter.mdimporter'

Also find this file:

'OmniOutliner.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/OmniOutliner.qlgenerator'

and copy it to:

'/Library/QuickLook/OmniOutliner.qlgenerator'

Quick Look will now work again.

Comment: under 10.13.2 and with OO 5.2., this did not work -- files are there, but even after restart quicklook results in a default orange OO  logo